# Magento 2: Add Customer Group Name in Transactional Email

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3

How to add customer group name in email template magento2

Comment: on which email template/ new order, customer creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to get customer group details from customer id.

```
protected $_customerSession;

protected $_customerGroupCollection;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $customerGroupCollection
) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;
}

public function getCustomerGroup()
{
    echo $currentGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); //Get customer group Id , you have already this so directly get name
    $collection = $this->_customerGroupCollection->load($currentGroupId); 
    echo $collection->getCustomerGroupCode();//Get group name
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: How can it use in email? @sumit

Comment: Pass customer group as variable in email function and use it in your email template.

Comment: Thank you it is working @Sumit

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Where should I put this code?

Comment: @MaxLeps Put this code in your class where the email template variables are defined.